# CJuiDatepicker not responding

Tags: jquery, yii

I created a new Yii application and created a master and add a datepicker for a field. It displays only textbox the picker is not coming.

```
        <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
                   'model'=>$model,
                    'attribute'=>'date_of_order',
                    'value'=>$model->date_of_order,
                            'options'=>array(
                            'autoSize'=>true,
                            'changeMonth'=>'true', 
                            'changeYear'=>'true',
                                'maxDate'=> 0,      
                            'yearRange'=>Yii::app()->params['YearRange'], 
                            ),
            'htmlOptions'=>array('size'=>'10')
            )); ?>
```

In console it shows some error like.

```
TypeError: this._get(...) is null

...,r=n._rgba=s._rgba,!1}),r.length?(r.join()==="0,0,0,0"&&t.extend(r,c.transparent...
```

I have used datepicker  lot of times before in similar way, but I don't understand why its not working now?

Comment: Can you give a little more information? Is jQuery being included correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You have to care about mainly on CSS and JS. There is no Problem on your Code you are using .
Look around these things for your [reference](http://www.waytoblogger.com/blog/technical/yii/register-js-css-files-in-yii-framework/) .

Your widget may missed some dependent CSS and JS . If that assets missing on your form you can just register scripts like that references

**Solution:**

```
$baseScriptUrl=Yii::app()->getAssetManager()->publish(Yii::getPathOfAlias('web.js.source.jui'));
/*JS files*/ 
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile($baseScriptUrl.'/js/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js',CClientScript::POS_END);

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile($baseScriptUrl.'/js/jquery-ui.min.js',CClientScript::POS_END);

/*CSS Files*/

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile($baseScriptUrl.'/css/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css');
```